# Is it grammatically correct to say "they left an empty spot" when referring to a departed person?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality

When someone you love is missing in your life (not necessarily dead), what is the correct way of saying they left an empty spot in your home?

"Kelly left an empty spot after she traveled"

Or

"Kelly's place is showing in this house" (which, I think, doesn't sound too grammatically correct)

Answer (score 2):

> Kelly left an empty spot after she traveled

I think you can get away with it; however, phrasing it like this ("Kelly left an empty spot") implies that Kelly chose to create that spot (maybe not as the main goal, but she *knowingly* left an empty spot).

When you're talking about a dead person (who did not commit suicide, I guess), I would change the phrasing to:

> There is an empty spot that Kelly used to fill.

It removes the implication that Kelly performed the action (leaving a spot by dying).

---

**Minor addition**

> Kelly left an empty spot after she traveled.

I think you mean to say

> Kelly left an empty spot when she traveled.

"After she traveled" means that she has stopped travelling when the empty spot is there.

That could be correct (e.g. she chose to stay abroad to live, therefore no longer traveling), but it could also be incorrect (she came back home after her travels).
To avoid confusion, I would say "when she traveled", to point out that the empty spot was only there **during** Kelly's travels.